# Stuck trying to decrypt AES 128 using mcrypt PHP

Tags: php, aes, mcrypt

I really need help, have spent hours trying to get this working to no avail.

I have data encrypted with AES.

```
Block size = 128
KeySize = 256
Mode = CBC
Padding = PKCS7
```

It comes as a POST to my script.

What I have so far is:

```
$encrypted = $_POST;

foreach ($encrypted as $k => $v) {
    $encrypted = trim($k);
}

$myKey = "FKQ5sTfotEDF7W07IpvyPFZ0IXeegs4b";

$myIV = "RFajS7JcDJDuAGAT"

$crypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $myKey, $encrypted , MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $myIV);

echo $crypttext;
```

Doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the way you are calling `$_POST` it looks like you want the raw post data. the `$_POST` variable contains an array of posted key=>value pairs. You should use

```
$encrypted = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Reference: http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php